# PyXB adding anyAttribute attributes to a generated Python class

Tags: python, xml, custom-attributes, pyxb

Given the schema:

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and after running the `pyxb -u <filename> -m person` command, how does create XML with arbitrary attributes using the generated bindings.

```
import person

p = person()
p.firstname = 'bob'
p.lastname  = 'bobbington'

#I want behavior like this
p.middlename = 'bobby'

#I would settle for behavior like this:
p.add_attribute( 'middlename', 'bobby' )

#Heck*, I'd even settle for:
temp_attr = pyxb.AttributeUse( name, value, blah, blah, blay )
p._AttributeMap.update( temp_attr.name(), temp_attr )
```

But no matter what I try, I cannot get the temporary attributes to show up when calling `p.toxml()`

Is this not supported? or have I overlooked something?

Edit: profanity removed.

Edit: Made a work around (the syntax and variable names are way off, but hopefully it helps enough for others to figure it out)

```
class PersonType():
    '''
    regular generated PersonType stuff here
    '''
    def add_attribute(self, name, value):
        t = pyxb.blahblahblah._AttributeUse(
            pyxb.blahblahblah._ExtendedName( None, attr_name),
            attr_name,
            pyxb.blahblah.StringDataType)
        t.setValue(self, value)  # or maybe _setValue
        self._AttributeMap[t.name()] = t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a complex type supports wildcard attributes, instances of the type have a method [wildcardAttributeMap()](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.binding.basis.complexTypeDefinition-class.html#wildcardAttributeMap) which is a map from extended names to unicode strings representing attribute values.  Per [this ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyxb/tickets/227/) there is currently no public API to manipulate this map, though you can probably do so manually.

Based on reviewing your question I've added [this ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyxb/tickets/233/) which confirms that even if you do put wildcard attributes into the map, they won't show up in the generated XML.

Sorry about that.  Looks like it's time to do another round of PyXB bug fixes.

Comment: No big deal. Other than that PyXB is fantastic. I found a work around though. I can't put code in comments so I'll edit the original question.

Comment: You should just be able to use `instance._setAttribute(name, value)` where `name` is an ExpandedName (namespace+localname, or just a local name with no namespace) and `value` is the unicode value of the attribute: no need to construct an AttributeUse.  The issues inspired by your question [have been fixed](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/commit/c31b68828969f14acd88504aeb61cd68407cf5e8) in the upstream github repository.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely cleaner. And thanks for still working on this library and making it better!